# Visual C++ MySQL Connector/C errors?

Tags: visual-c++, mysql-connector

My source code results in this:

```
// MySQL.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#define TABLE_OF_INTEREST "some_table"
#define SERVER_NAME "mysql_server"
#define DB_USER "user"
#define DB_USERPASS "pa55w0rd"
#define DB_NAME "db_name"
#define NEWLINE "\n"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MYSQL *hnd = NULL; // mysql connection handle
    const char *sinf = NULL; // mysql server information 
    if(!mysql_real_connect(hnd, SERVER_NAME, DB_USER, DB_USERPASS, DB_NAME, 0, NULL, 0)
        cout << "Something happened.";
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MySQL, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  MySQL.cpp
1>MySQL.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32
1>c:\users\josiah\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MySQL\Release\MySQL.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved external
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't think there issues with the source, I just need help on how to figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a reference to a lib. The C connector should have come with a .lib, add it to the additional input for the linker

Comment: What would the .lib be called?

Comment: libmysql.lib and it's probable location is C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C x.x.x\lib

Comment: Ah, nope, I've had libmysql.lib added the whole time.

Comment: Are you using the debug libs for debug build and release libs for release build? have you tried adding mysqlclient.lib?

Comment: I am using the correct libs, and I have tried adding mysqlclient.lib
Would my using the 64-bit connectors have anything to do with it?

Comment: It might if your project is not 64-bit.